# Does a group created using `groupadd` have a default password?

Tags: linux, group

I created a group using the following command:

```
sudo groupadd myGroup
```

Then I tried to run `gedit` and set its primary group to `myGroup`:

```
sg myGroup gedit
```

But `sg` is asking me for what I assume is the group password.

Does a group created using `groupadd` have a default password?

---

**Edit:**

When I make `myGroup` part of my user's groups, then `sg` no longer asks me for the group password. But I do not want to make `myGroup` part of my user's groups.

Comment: Did you make sure your user became a member of `myGroup`. I am not seeing that part in the question.

Comment: @Tigger I edited my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, by default [`groupadd`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/groupadd.8.html) doesn’t set group passwords (which means they are disabled, and only users who are members of a group can use the group). To set a password, use the `-p` option to `groupadd` (but read its documentation first), or better yet, run [`gpasswd`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/gpasswd.1.html).

Comment: I did `gpasswd myGroup` and set a password. And then I did `sg myGroup gedit`, but `sg` gave me an "Invalid password." error when I entered the group password.

Comment: Weird, it works for me...

Comment: I'll try it on a fresh install of Linux.

Comment: It worked for me on Ubuntu 9.04 and Ubuntu 16.04, but it didn't work on Ubuntu 10.10!